# Exec a function from one class to another in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a function in one class, this function exec when you click in a button. I want to exec other fuction when in click it. 
This is the first function

```
public cancel() {
    this.options.isEditing = false;
}
```

And I want to exect this function on the other. He's in another class.

```
public cancel_editable() {
this.address = this.snap;
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a function in a class from another class in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105864/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-a-class-from-another-class-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 0):

For this we can use rxjs library. Make use of Subject or BehaviorSubject. Please refer the link below:

https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/

This will give you an idea how to use the same. We can emit value from one class and subscribe in other.

Please try if any more help you contact.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Please contact if any more help required.